# ¿Como crear un servidor local de NodeJs para conectar varias computadoras?

Tags: nodejs

Disculpen, soy nuevo en este mundo de los Framework, anteriormente he usado NodeJs un poco y me preguntaba si es posible crear un servidor donde conectar varias maquinas para abrir el archivo y se conecten todas al http; de igual manera, el como o dónde podría encontrar un poco de información del como realizar esto.

Comment: Abrir cuál archivo? Conectarse a qué http?

Comment: Cuando estaba haciendo un proyecto con compañeros de la universidad, usamos express y nodejs para crear un servidor web, configurabamos un puerto y al entrar al navegador accediamos a nuestro sitio web, pero todo era a traves de un archivo que configurabamos llamado ¨Api.js¨ todo de manera local. Ahorita trato de crear un sitio web donde se conecten varias computadoras y no se si sea posible hacerlo de esta misma manerea solo que todas se conecten a este sitio web creado con express y nodejs al igual que sea local

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Es tan simple como instalar nodejs y poner a correr el script deseado. Requiere programarlo, pero no es demasiado complicado.

Comment: Ok, Tengo actualmente un proyecto donde necesito crear un web, esta web tiene que ser de manera local y la tienen que conectar diversas computadoras. La verdad nunca he conectado varias computadoras a una web de esta manera. Donde estoy asignan un espacio en sus servidores y ahi guardamos nuestros datos. Lo que pensaba era crear una web con NodeJs y Express
Con el archivo que cree lo pensaba meter en un espacio de los servidores que tienen dentro y que todas las computadoras de manera individual las abran en sus respectivas computadoras. Aunque realmente no se si funcione o exista otra manera

Comment: Como comente, soy realmente nuevo en todo este tema, y apenas estoy comenzando a construir mi camino como programador en una empresa